# "conversion to 'float' from 'int' may alter its value"

Tags: c, compiler-errors, floating-point, variable-assignment

I researched the error and haven't been able to find it. Also I am new to this. I want to learn the basics of C and here is my first program. I want to modify `sum` in the function `calc` so it is a `float` in case someone divides for example `2/5`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getNumber1() {
    int myNumber1;
    printf("\n gib eine Zahl ein: ");
    scanf("%d", &myNumber1);
    return myNumber1;
}

int getNumber2() {
    int myNumber2;
    printf("\n gib eine weitere Zahl ein: ");
    scanf("%d", &myNumber2);
    return myNumber2;
}

char getOp() {
    char myOp;
    printf("\n gib einen Operanten ein: ");
    scanf(" %c", &myOp);
    return myOp;
}

void calc(int number1, int number2, char op) {
    if (op == '+') {
        int sum = number1 + number2;
        printf("\n\n%d %c %d = %d", number1, op, number2, sum);
    }
    if (op == '-') {
        int sum = number1 - number2;
        printf("\n\n%d %c %d = %d", number1, op, number2, sum);
    }
    if (op == '*') {
        int sum = number1 * number2;
        printf("\n\n%d %c %d = %d", number1, op, number2, sum);
    }
    if (op == '/') {
        float sum = number1 / number2;
        printf("\n\n%d %c %d = %.2f", number1, op, number2, sum);
    }
}

int main() {
    int cont = 1;
    while (cont == 1) {
        int number1 = getNumber1();
        int number2 = getNumber2();
        char op = getOp();
        calc(number1, number2, op);
        printf("\nMoechten Sie weitere Berechnungen durchfuehren? (1 fuer Ja, 0 fuer Nein): ");
        scanf("%d", &cont);
    }
    printf("\nDanke und auf Wiedersehen.");
    return 0;
}
```

But I get the error that `conversion to float from int may alter its value`. Why is that and how can I solve the error?

Comment: Unrelated: prefer `double` when dealing with floating-point numbers (forget `float` exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler issues the message because an integer value is assigned to a variable of the floating type `float`.

In this statement

```
float sum = number1 / number2;
```

the expression `number1 / number2` is evaluated using the integer arithmetic. So assigning to a variable of the type float does not make a great sense.

Instead write for exameple

```
float sum = ( float )number1 / number2;
```

Comment: still the same error. sum is also always 0. thx for answer!

Comment: @PeterKirsch Show values of number1 and number2 you are using.

Comment: how do i "show" ? just post a screenshot? sorry i am new to this.

Comment: @PeterKirsch  What are number1 and number2 equal to?

Comment: @PeterKirsch Here is an output of your updated program  gib eine Zahl ein: 1

 gib eine weitere Zahl ein: 2

 gib einen Operanten ein: /


1 / 2 = 0.50
Moechten Sie weitere Berechnungen durchfuehren? (1 fuer Ja, 0 fuer Nein):

Comment: yes u are right. thank you! so there are different arithmetics. i will inform myself on this topic.